# input file multiple

Tags: javascript, html

Como muestro el nombre de los archivos seleccionados, el tamaño de los archivos seleccionados y el tipo de archivo.

He intentado con este código, pero no se muestra nada al abrir el navegador.

```html
    <input type="file" id=files multiple>
    <script>
        var insertar_en= document.querySelector("#archivos ul");
        File_in = document.querySelector("#files")
        File_in.onchange = function(e){
            var files = e.target.files;
            for(var i=0,f;f=files[i];++i){
                var archivo = document.createElement("li");
                archivo.innerHTML = f.name + " - (<b>" + f.type + "</b>)" + f.size;
                insertar_en.appendChild(archivo)
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: como tienes el html?

Answer (score 0):

Similar a tu código, este hace lo que estás buscando.

> Muestra el nombre del archivo, la extensión del archivo, el peso del archivo (en bytes), y la última fecha de modificación del archivo; en una lista `ul li`.

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />

// Aqui se ve todo la info del archivo
<output id="list"></output>
```

El JavaScript. Es necesario primero verificar si la API del archivo es compatible con el navegador:

```
// verificar si la API soporta archivo. 
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) { 
  // muy bien
} else { 
 alert('la API de archivos no es compatible con este navegador '); 
}
```

Luego la super función:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) { 

 var files = evt.target.files; 
 var output = []; 
 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) { 
 
 output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ', 
 f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ', 
 f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>'); 
 
} 

document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>'; 

} 

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```